# XSD Sequence with optional elements and any

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

Is it possible to define a complex type sequence with optional elements followed by n optional any elements?
Currently I have this XSD which violaets UPA:

```
<xs:complexType name="itemtype">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="uuid" type="uuidtype"/>
        <xs:element name="lastname" type="nametype"/>
        <xs:element name="isActive" minOccurs="0" type="isactivetype"/>
        <xs:element name="countries_scope" type="countryscopetype"/>
        <xs:element name="origin" minOccurs="0" type="nametype"/>
        <xs:element name="url" minOccurs="0" type="nametype"/>
        <xs:element name="email" minOccurs="0" type="emailtype"/>
        <xs:element name="description" minOccurs="0" type="nametype"/>
        <xs:element name="town" minOccurs="0" type="nametype"/>
        <xs:element name="role" minOccurs="0" type="nametype"/>
        <xs:element name="source" minOccurs="0" type="nametype"/>
        <xs:element name="origin_zip" minOccurs="0" type="nametype"/>
        <xs:element name="town_zip" minOccurs="0" type="nametype"/>
        <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

A possible XML could be:

```
<item>
  <uuid>1</uuid>
  <lastname>Yanick</lastname>
  <country_scope>CHE</country_scope>
  <role>Student</role>
  <age>24</age>
</item>
```

Here only the optional role is used and age would be one any element.

Comment: More information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_Particle_Attribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple. THe last element bevore the any can't be an optional.
This XSD would work:

```
<xs:complexType name="itemtype">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="uuid" type="uuidtype"/>
    <xs:element name="lastname" type="nametype"/>
    <xs:element name="isActive" minOccurs="0" type="isactivetype"/>
    <xs:element name="origin" minOccurs="0" type="nametype"/>
    <xs:element name="url" minOccurs="0" type="nametype"/>
    <xs:element name="email" minOccurs="0" type="emailtype"/>
    <xs:element name="description" minOccurs="0" type="nametype"/>
    <xs:element name="town" minOccurs="0" type="nametype"/>
    <xs:element name="role" minOccurs="0" type="nametype"/>
    <xs:element name="source" minOccurs="0" type="nametype"/>
    <xs:element name="origin_zip" minOccurs="0" type="nametype"/>
    <xs:element name="town_zip" minOccurs="0" type="nametype"/>
    <xs:element name="countries_scope" type="countryscopetype"/>
    <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
</xs:sequence>
```